# Is JwtSecurityTokenHandler thread safe

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, jwt

I'm using `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` to issue tokens in a aspnet core web api app:

```
JwtSecurityToken token = BuildJwtSecurityToken(...);
public string toks = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
```

each time a token is requested and created, a new JwtSecurityTokenHandler is instantiated, can I use a global instance of it and use it for every token generation?

```
private JwtSecurityTokenHandler handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
private GenToken(JwtSecurityToken token) => handler.WriteToken(token);
```

Is there any problems to use like this?

Comment: I know ReadToken and ValidateToken are, and it looks like WriteToken is as well. https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/rel/5.2.0/src/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/JwtSecurityTokenHandler.cs

Answer (score 6):

Docs say instance members for `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwtsecuritytokenhandler(v=vs.114).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Most examples I see, such as [this one on blog.wille-zone.de](https://blog.wille-zone.de/post/secure-azure-functions-with-jwt-token/), create it separately for each request.

I would not get too clever on this; even if it's currently threadsafe, noone here can commit Microsoft to keeping it that way.

If you do want a commitment from them, you could start by raising an issue at https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet. They can write it into the specification/code/docs.

Answer (score -1):

#### It seems that the two most important functions are thread-safe!

*I had the same issue in a high concurrent system and analyzed it to uncover the truth.*

#### The Code that we are talking about:

```cs
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;

namespace SafeTokenHandler;

public static class JwtSecurityTokenExtensions
{
    private static readonly JwtSecurityTokenHandler JwtSecurityTokenHandlerShared = new();
    
    public static string CompileToString(this JwtSecurityToken token) => JwtSecurityTokenHandlerShared.WriteToken(token);

    public static JwtSecurityToken ToJwtSecurityToken(this string token) => JwtSecurityTokenHandlerShared.ReadJwtToken(token);
}
```

### Benchmark Results

#### WriteToken

```
BenchmarkDotNet v0.13.11, macOS Sonoma 14.0 (23A344) [Darwin 23.0.0]
Apple M2 Pro, 1 CPU, 10 logical and 10 physical cores
.NET SDK 8.0.100
  [Host]     : .NET 8.0.0 (8.0.23.53103), Arm64 RyuJIT AdvSIMD
  DefaultJob : .NET 8.0.0 (8.0.23.53103), Arm64 RyuJIT AdvSIMD
```

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Ratio | Gen0 | Gen1 | Allocated | Alloc Ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| JwtInstance | 1,403.7 ns | 5.11 ns | 4.27 ns | 1.00 | 0.9537 | 0.0172 | 7.8 KB | 1.00 |
| JwtStatic | 479.9 ns | 1.39 ns | 1.16 ns | 0.34 | 0.3195 | - | 2.62 KB | 0.34 |

#### ReadJwtToken

```
BenchmarkDotNet v0.13.11, macOS Sonoma 14.0 (23A344) [Darwin 23.0.0]
Apple M2 Pro, 1 CPU, 10 logical and 10 physical cores
.NET SDK 8.0.100
  [Host]     : .NET 8.0.0 (8.0.23.53103), Arm64 RyuJIT AdvSIMD
  DefaultJob : .NET 8.0.0 (8.0.23.53103), Arm64 RyuJIT AdvSIMD
```

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Ratio | Gen0 | Gen1 | Allocated | Alloc Ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| JwtInstance | 1,806.3 ns | 7.24 ns | 6.78 ns | 1.00 | 0.8755 | 0.0095 | 7.16 KB | 1.00 |
| JwtStatic | 869.9 ns | 1.79 ns | 1.40 ns | 0.48 | 0.2403 | 0.0010 | 1.97 KB | 0.28 |

#### WriteToken Method Testing

Code Snippet:

```cs
[Fact]
public void CompileToString_MultiThread()
{
    var expected = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    var upper = Random.Shared.Next(1000, 10000);
    
    for (var i = 0; i < upper; i++)
    {
        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
            issuer: "me",
            audience: "you",
            new[] { new Claim("sub", i.ToString()) });
        
        expected.Add(i, JwtUtility.CompileToString(token));
    }

    var actual = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, string>();   
    
    Parallel.For(0, upper, i =>
    {
        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
            issuer: "me",
            audience: "you",
            new[] { new Claim("sub", i.ToString()) });

        var addResult = actual.TryAdd(i, token.CompileToString());
        Assert.True(addResult, $"Failed to add {i} to actual");
        
    });
    
    Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
    
    foreach (var (expectedKey, expectedValue) in expected)
    {
        Assert.Equal(expectedValue, actual[expectedKey]);
    }
}
```

#### ReadJwtToken Method Testing

Code Snippet:

```cs
[Fact]
public void ToJwtSecurityToken_MultiThread()
{
    var expected = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    var upper = Random.Shared.Next(1000, 10000);
    
    for (var i = 0; i < upper; i++)
    {
        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
            issuer: "me",
            audience: "you",
            new[] { new Claim("sub", i.ToString()) });
        
        expected.Add(i, JwtUtility.CompileToString(token));
    }
    
    var actual = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, JwtSecurityToken>();
    
    Parallel.For(0, upper, i =>
    {
        var addResult = actual.TryAdd(i, expected[i].ToJwtSecurityToken());
        Assert.True(addResult, $"Failed to add {i} to actual");
    });
    
    foreach (var (expectedKey, expectedValue) in expected)
    {
        Assert.Equal(expectedValue, actual[expectedKey].CompileToString());
    }
}
```

#### Conclusion

The conducted benchmarks and functional tests indicate that the `WriteToken` and `ReadJwtToken` methods are thread-safe.
These results are crucial for applications requiring high concurrency, ensuring reliable and consistent performance under various load conditions.

- *I guess there is room for improvement*
- [The source code and doc](https://github.com/SorenZ/JwtSecurityTokenHandler)